# Show All Column Values

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to show a column in a matrix table when there is no row in the dataset. E.g in Excel you can create a manual table as below and when data exists it populates according. So if the dataset has no row for 100 Days + this should show as 0. But in Power BI the columns only show if there is data. So the tables are all different sizes.

What i want to show is the below but i am only getting 3 columns in power bi (0-1 days, 2-7 days and 8-14 days) and not the whole groups

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Yasir

Comment: You probably want to [create a dimension table](https://radacad.com/basics-of-modeling-in-power-bi-what-is-a-dimension-table-and-why-say-no-to-a-single-big-table) for your columns.